# XAMPP configuration issue: unable to access external files/urls

Tags: php, xampp

I have recently set up XAMPP. The setup was straightforward but I don't seem to know the correct tweak to allow it to speak to the outside web world.

No matter how I try to read an external URL, it tells me where to get off.

(In PHP) I've tried the simple file_get_contents route. When that failed, somebody pointed me to curl. I enabled that in php.ini but that failed too.

I get the very unhelpful "Unable to open file"

```
Fatal error: Unable to open "https://earth.esa.int/documents/10174/1514862/Swarm_Level-2_TEC_Product_Description" in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\PdfToText.phpclass:1665 Stack trace: #0  #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\PdfToText.phpclass on line 1665
```

I know this seems like an error with the class PdfToText (above) but it's just a way of showing the error. Take the file from between the quote marks, try to load it and it's fine. It doesn't want to open files from the outside world no matter what's tried.

I assume that it's a port/proxy/something but I've Googled all day in and out of stackoverflow and I cannot see the same problem anywhere.

Comment: Does `file_get_contents('http://example.com/');` work?

Comment: I just tried this after your suggestion:<pre>Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.ns.nl): failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.</pre>

Comment: I know this is going to sound like a silly question but "Are you connected to the internet"?

Comment: Connect to here on the same computer so I guess so :)

Comment: More sensible question "Did you activate the `php_openssl` extension in `php.ini`"

Comment: Not such a silly question though as I assume XAMPP is positively not connected to the internet - it reads local files perfectly

Comment: I found php_openssl commented out so I've fixed that, restarted Apache and MySQL but alas ended up with the same file_get_contents failure as above.

Comment: Have you checked the php error log in case there is any other useful info about the error

Comment: Weirdly there was no /logs directory and thus the php_error_log file didn't exist. Having created it, the log file, now created, is repeating the text of the errors listed on this - so no further info to report

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix:

Find your php.ini file:

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```

look for **allow_url_fopen** and set it to On

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

Explanation:

This error happens because when you use functions like file_get_contents or fopen, you are handling file pointers, what allow_url_fopen will let you do is, resolve the url, create a tcp connection and create a network file pointer to that tcp connection, which will be handled by php as it were a file.

For security reasons, this setting is disabled on some installations.

Check the docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

Comment: phpinfo(): Loaded Configuration File  C:\xampp\php\php.ini

Comment: Just below this: "allow_url_include=Off" - set this to On, restarted Apache and same issue. Set it back to Off